# QOpenGLFrameBufferObject: binding texture name from texture() gives InvalidOperation error

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

In my application I have a module that manages rendering using OpenGL, and renders the results into `QOpenGLFrameBufferObjects`. I know this much works, because I'm able to save their contents using `QOpenGLFrameBufferObject::toImage()` and see the render.

I am now attempting to take the texture ID returned from `QOpenGLFrameBufferObject::texture()`, bind it as a normal OpenGL texture and render it into a `QOpenGLWidget` viewport using a fullscreen quad. (I'm using this two-step method because I'm not aware of a way to get around the fact that `QOpenGLWidgets` each work in their own context, but that's a different story.)

The problem here is that `glBindTexture()` returns `InvalidOperation` when I call it. According to the OpenGL documentation, this is because "[The] texture was previously created with a target that doesn't match that of [the input]." However, I created the frame buffer object by passing `GL_TEXTURE_2D` into the constructor, and am passing the same in as the target to `glBindTexture()`, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. There isn't much documentation online about how to correctly use `QOpenGLFrameBufferObject::texture()`.

Other supplementary information, in case it helps:

- The creation of the frame buffer object doesn't set any special formats. They're left at whatever defaults Qt uses. As far as I know, this means it also has no depth or stencil attachments as of yet, though once I've got the basics working this will probably change.
- Binding the FBO before binding its texture doesn't seem to make a difference.
- `QOpenGLFrameBufferObject::isValid()` returns true;
- Calling `glIsTexture()` on the texture handle returns false, but I'm not sure why this would be given that it's a value provided to me by Qt for the purposes of binding an OpenGL texture. The OpenGL documentation does mention that "a name returned by glGenTextures, but not yet associated with a texture by calling glBindTexture, is not the name of a texture", but here I can't bind it anyway.
- I'm attempting to bind the texture in a different context to the one the FBO was created in (ie. the `QOpenGLWidget`'s context instead of the render module's context).

I'll provide some code, but a lot of what I have is specific to the systems that exist in the rendering module, so there's only a small amount of relevant OpenGL code.

In the render module context:

```
QOpenGLFrameBufferObject fbo = new QOpenGLFrameBufferObject(QSize(...), GL_TEXTURE_2D);

// Do some rendering in this context later
```

In the `QOpenGLWidget` context, after having rendered to the frame buffer in the rendering module:

```
GLuint textureId = fbo->texture();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId)) // Invalid operation
```

---

EDIT: It turns out the culprit was that my contexts weren't actually being shared, as I'd misinterpreted what the `Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts` application attribute did. Once I made them properly shared the issue was fixed.

Comment: Please show the code. What have multiple QOpenGLWidget to do with your problem? Are you creating the texture in the correct context/widget?

Comment: "*Calling glIsTexture() on the texture handle returns false.*" Then it is not a texture.

Comment: I mentioned the QOpenGLWidgets because they each have their own context, so I am trying to take a FBO created in one context and bind its texture in another. I would have expected this to be OK, because textures are shareable and all my QOpenGLContexts are set to share globally.

Comment: I've got sharing of a texture from `QOpenGLFrameBufferObject` to a different context in my project, and it works fine. Can you catch a moment when the texture becomes invalid by inserting `glBindTexture()` everywhere? It should be valid just after the FBO render, right?

Comment: I actually have a feeling that my contexts aren't being shared. I thought that Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts would mean all contexts were shared, but apparently it just means QOpenGLWidget contexts specifically. If I check my render context with the GL widget, apparently they aren't sharing. Is there a way to get that to work? Really I want to call setShareContext(renderingContext) for each QOpenGLWidget, but I can't see a way to do that.